# Can’t SSH into GitLab when it’s accessible via HAProxy

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a GitLab instance in docker-compose on a VM in my home network.

It's running behind HAProxy proxy and accessible on `git.example.com:443`.

To be able to access them both inside my home network and outside my home network, I have to have the DNS point `git.example.com` to the HAProxy address.

Because of this, when I try to SSH to `git.example.com`, it tries to SSH into the proxy server instead.

So I'm trying to be able to forward it so that if someone tries to SSH on `ssh.git.example.com:22` (or port 443), it will redirect it to `media.lan.example.com:4002`, because port `4000`/`4001`/`4002` are the ports docker uses for the container for ports `80`/`443`/`22` respectively.

How can I achieve this? To be able to SSH on port `22` or `443` at `ssh.git.example.com` without having to have the client change any of their config.

My HAProxy config:

```
frontend http
    bind example.com:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    mode http
    use_backend gitlab-backend if { hdr(host) -i git.example.com }

frontend https
    bind example.com:443 ssl crt /certs/cert.pem
    mode http
    use_backend gitlab-backend if { hdr(host) -i git.example.com }

backend gitlab-backend
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    server gitlab1 media.lan.example.com:4001 ssl check verify none
    mode http

backend gitlab-ssh-backend
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    mode tcp
    server gitlabssh1 media.lan.example.com:4002 check

frontend gitlab-ssh-frontend
    bind ssh.git.example.com:443 ssl crt /certs/cert.pem
    use_backend gitlab-ssh-backend
    mode tcp
```

Comment: Seems like you could do something with IPTables to route SSH traffic to the proper destination. But in general, HAProxy is mainly for web traffic, so I don’t think it would be something easily set with HAProxy.

Comment: @JakeGould is there any way that I would be able to achieve clients being able to ssh at `ssh.git.example.com` or `git.example.com` in a way where they don't have to configure a different port themselves?

Comment: Like I said, “Seems like you could do something with IPTables to route SSH traffic to the proper destination.” Meaning an IPTables config would detect where the request is coming from and route accordingly.